# Is there a way to get a NetSuite Running Inventory Total by Lot via Saved Search or other?

Tags: transactions, netsuite, inventory, saved-searches

The use case is a running total search of inventory quantity for particular item / lot / location over time to be able to view inventory 'as of' the time of that transaction and each transactions impact on on-hand to reconcile counts and find mistakes and discrepancies. I'm still a bit perplexed that this isn't a native function of an inventory system like NetSuite...if anyone has a simpler way I'm sure many would be eager to hear.

That the system doesn't separate 'change in on hand' as a concept for reporting vs. a generic 'Quantity' without customization is a bit wild, and I'm still somewhat convinced I'm missing something despite how many folks have told me 'it doesn't work that way'. e.g. like a treating a bill or invoice Qty that did not affect your stock count the same as the receipt or item fulfillment that did, from a reporting / data standpoint. Quantity Ordered, Committed, B/O, Invoiced, Billed, Planned, etc. are all distinct concepts from 'Net Change in On Hand', which I can't find an independent treatment of.

**Inventory Valuation Detail Report** w. Running Balance = True is the closest thing I've found natively, but will not split out quantity by individual lots so that makes it much less useful for companies heavily using lot-tracked inventory like in sensitive manufacturing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, here's the search criteria cobbled together to get the running totals:

Item Lot Running Inventory Total (Transaction Search)

Here's my sketch of a list of relevant transaction types, if anyone has a comprehensive resource to point to, I made a post specifically on this - thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366671/looking-for-an-official-list-of-netsuite-transactions-impacting-on-hand-quantity).

- Assembly Build
- Assembly Unbuild
- Cash Sale
- Inventory Adjustment
- Inventory Count
- Inventory Distribution
- Inventory Transfer
- Inventory Worksheet
- Item Fulfillment
- Item Receipt
- Production Order Completion
- Production Order Issue
- Return Authorization
- Transfer
- Transfer Order
- Vendor Return Authorization

Criteria:

Filter  Set
Inventory Detail : Number   = not None
Posting = True
Type    Any of (the bulleted list above)
Formula (Numeric)   =1  case when {inventorydetail.inventorynumber} = {itemnumber.inventorynumber} then 1 else 0 end
Optional:       To limit initial run results (performance)
Location    desired default for filter
Item    choose one item for filter
Item Number : Number    choose one existing lot of item selected

Available Filters:
Item, Item Number : Number (Lot), Location

Results:
Critical to sort by Date (ascending) Then Internal ID (ascending)

This will help show you transactions that happened out of order and may cause negative stocks.

| FIELD | FUNCTION | FORMULA | CUSTOM LABEL | SUMMARY LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date |  |  |  |  |
| Item : Display Name |  |  |  |  |
| Type |  |  |  |  |
| Location |  |  |  |  |
| Document Number |  |  |  |  |
| Created From |  |  |  |  |
| Formula (Numeric) |  | case when {type}='Item Fulfillment' then {quantity}*-1 else {quantity} end | Quantity |  |
| Inventory Detail : Number |  |  |  |  |
| Inventory Detail : Bin Number |  |  |  |  |
| Formula (Numeric) |  | case when {quantity} <0 then {inventorydetail.quantity}*-1 when {type} = 'Item Fulfillment' then {inventorydetail.quantity}*-1 else {inventorydetail.quantity} end | Lot Qty |  |
| Formula (Numeric) |  | sum/* comment */(case when {quantity}<0 then {inventorydetail.quantity}*-1 when {type} = 'Item Fulfillment' then {inventorydetail.quantity}*-1 else {inventorydetail.quantity} END) OVER(PARTITION BY {formulatext} ORDER BY {lineuniquekey} ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) | Running Balance |  |